# What type of drill should I get?

Tags: drill, hole, mount, self-assembly-furniture

I am moving into my house in a few weeks, and I want to get a general purpose drill for use around the house. I learned that there are different types of drills: power drill, hammer drill, and impact drill. Also, I've seen drills that are 8V all the way to 20V.

I want to use it for making holes in drywall for hanging TVs, picture frames, etc... I also want to be able to use it to assemble furniture, for example from Ikea.

Comment: I went with corded cause it never runs out of power and around a house there is always a wall plug. Also a few years later don't need a new battery.

Comment: Yeah, for like $10 you can get a corded drill that will outperform $50 battery drills, especially if it's just spent 6 months on the shelf.

Comment: If you've never used a drill/driver before (and it sounds like you haven't), I'd strongly recommend that you _NOT_ use it for assembling your flat-pack furniture!! It's _way_ too easy to over tighten the screws and strip out the cheap particle board and ruin the piece. Now, I use a driver all the time to assemble mine, and it makes it go _much_ faster, but I've used one for a _long_ time and know exactly what kind of touch the trigger takes to get a 1/4 turn instead of 4 turns, and that can make all the difference between tight and ruined.

Comment: Unless your house is made of concrete (poured or block) or stone, you do _not_ want a hammer drill. They're very expensive tools for putting holes in wood (and they're not really designed for that), but they're perfect for putting holes in concrete/stone.

Comment: @AndreiMihailevski I have at least 3 corded drills that I haven't used in years.  The convenience of the cordless drills so greatly outweighs the hassle of the corded drills that I simply never use them any longer.  But to each his own.  BTW, if you visit almost any construction site you'll see cordless tools being used almost exclusively.

Comment: NEVER use power tools to assemble IKEA furniture (unless you’re drilling *holes* obviously).   Keep in mind “drills” have 2 applications these days: driving screws and drilling holes.  **The 2 applications need different speeds**.  The typical drill-driver maxes out at about 450 RPM, too fast for screws, *way* too slow for any drill that’ll fit in it. They make pure drills that spin more like 1500 RPM; they’re the cheapies but I cherish them ... *for drilling*.

Comment: @jwh20 When I drill in production, I want corded because actual drilling takes a LOT of energy.  When I screw in production, I use a speed wrench.

Answer (score 2):

A basic [drill/driver](https://www.lowes.com/pl/Cordless--Drills-Drills-drivers-Power-tools-Tools/4294607722?refinement=4294776932&int_cmp=DrillsDrivers%3AC%3ATools%3AMerch%3Acordless_drills_visual_taxonomy) will meet the needs you mentioned.

[What is drill/driver?](https://powertooladdict.com/what-is-a-cordless-drill-driver/)

I think a cordless one would be more convenient. I own the Dewalt 20volt max but you could get away with 12volt max if you are not going to be doing heavy drilling. Dewalt's and their batteries are not cheap, I have set of [craftsman](https://www.lowes.com/pd/CRAFTSMAN-V20-20-Volt-Max-1-2-in-Brushless-Cordless-Drill-Charger-Included/1001106076) cordless tools in another location and they are more affordable. There are many options, [Rigid](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-18-Volt-Lithium-Ion-Cordless-2-Speed-1-2-in-Compact-Drill-Driver-Kit-with-2-Ah-Battery-Charger-and-Tool-Bag-R8600521K/311454336) is another.

You want one that has a clutch or adjustment stops so when you are assembling cabinets you can set it to a weaker torque setting to avoid driving the screws too deep.

Comment: Sorry but a 12v drill is practically useless. If OP starts getting comfortable with their handywork then they will quickly find that they need 18v or more. Buy it once and buy it right!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus not sure I agree with you. I have a small dewalt 12v from 4-5 year ago and I still use it regularly building things from raise bed to 4x6 chicken coop. Sure nothing heavy but from the use OP told, a 12v would be plenty enough. I do have a bigger coded drill for when I need more power (redirect the electric drier exaulst  outside). I have never owned a big battery drill but I suspect it would have been hard to drill with a 4inch hole saw.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you need is a decent drill/driver. I strongly recommend getting something that is part of a system. I have a bunch of Ryobi stuff, which is from Home Depot, but there are several other brands. Typically they have a battery (e.g., 18V) that is compatible with a whole bunch of different tools. Usually there will be a starter pack of drill/driver + battery + charger, but sometimes with multiple tools at a good price, and then you add additional tools (hammer drill, circular saw, etc.) as you need them, sharing the battery(ies) and charger.

- Drywall - Actually, you don't want to use a drill at all for drywall. Just use a [Drywall Saw](https://amzn.to/2Oldoyu):

[image: Drywall Saw]

- Hanging TVs, picture frames, etc. - Use a drill/driver to drill pilot holes through the drywall into studs and then screw through the drywall into the studs.
- Assemble Furniture - Can be done with a manual screwdriver, but a drill/driver will make some of it go a little faster.

For screwdriving only, almost anything will do. But 12V or more is best, and given current pricing I would recommend an 18V system for more power when drilling as well as the ability to add other tools later.